# SSL Issues with a subdomain

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, certificate

I have a website that has a webmail client on it.

Here is a copy of the structure

```
web_root/
  mail/ <--Webmail client
  index.html <--Normal website
```

I am trying to have a subdomain point from `mail.site.com` to `site.com/mail/` all while having this using a SSL based connection.

I am aware of the following:

- DNS Records only point to IP addresses and won't benefit me here
- I need two separate SSL Certifications for site.com and mail.site.com *(which I have)*
- I need to use two `VirtualHosts` inside my httpd.conf

---

When I try to connect to mail.site.com everything works fine. Green little lock in browser, shows correct page, etc. **However**, the issue I am experiencing is that when I try to connect to site.com I get the red lock and an error stating that "Your connection is not safe!". When I click past the error it shows the `mail/` directory and not the proper page. Additionally, when I look at the SSL certificate, the certificate is for `mail.site.com` and not `site.com` like it should be

I am clearly mis-configuring things, and I have searched through several similar posts to no avail.

**In summary, how do I configure my httpd.conf file to allow for all requests for `site.com` to use the appropriate certificate and go the right location AND for all requests for `mail.site.com` to use the appropriate certificate and display the contents of `web_root/mail/`?**

---

Apache configuration files for reference.

### httpd.conf

```
ServerRoot "/xampp/apache"
Listen 80

LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
    User daemon
    Group daemon
</IfModule>

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs"

<Directory "/xampp/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.html index.htm \
                   default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html default.htm \
                   home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/xampp/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/xampp/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile "conf/magic"
</IfModule>

Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
Include "conf/extra/httpd-proxy.conf"
Include "conf/extra/httpd-default.conf"
Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf"

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
    Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf

<IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none

<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    <IfModule mod_proxy_ajp.c>
        Include "conf/extra/httpd-ajp.conf"
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

### ssl-httpd.conf

```
NameVirtualHost 64.255.105.66:443

<VirtualHost 64.255.105.66:443>
    DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName site.com
    ServerAlias site.com
    ServerAdmin support@site.com

    ErrorLog "/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
    TransferLog "/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "C:\\SSL\\site\\cert.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\\SSL\\site\\privkey.key"
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        SSLRequireSSL
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    CustomLog "/xampp/apache/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>                                  


<VirtualHost 64.255.105.66:443>
    DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs/mail"
    ServerName mail.site.com
    ServerAlias site.com
    ServerAdmin support@site.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "C:\\SSL\\mail_site\\cert.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\\SSL\\mail_site\\privkey.key"

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\mail\\">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        SSLRequireSSL
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there are other things as well, but you have the same server alias site.com on both virtualhosts - you don't need a serveralias directive, so you should drop this from  the mail virtualhost as this is a cause of some of your problems.

FWIW, I have a similar config on one of my setups (but for 2 totally different domains).  Differences in our configs are:

1. I use a directive NameVirtualHost *:443   (Although I'm not sure this is
   even required at all anymore)
2. I use <Virtualhost *:443> for binding my sites

Other comments -

For the mail virtualhost, as you are doing a redirection, you can have a much simpler virtualhost - I'd try something like

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName mail.site.com

SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile "C:\\SSL\\mail_site\\cert.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\\SSL\\mail_site\\privkey.key"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)     https://example.com/mail/$1 [L,R]
</VirtualHost>
```

(I had to use example.com rather then site.com in the rewrite rule above - change as appropriate - This appears to be a limit of this site !)

Comment: Your answer did not work but helped me find the solution lol. I found that when I deleted the server alias line it broke _everything_ lol. I ended up correcting the server aliases and server names for both and it worked!